# Facebook Graph API edge for getting object params of a Pixel

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pixel, facebook-pixel

Is there any graph edge available from where i can see which event params are associated with a particular ad pixel?

[image]

[Facebook pixel reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/reference/)

I have tried exploring

```
me/adaccounts?fields=id,account_id,name,adspixels{name,id}
```

but it does not give any information regarding the ad-pixel params. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unsure what you are asking, what exact info do you want to get? Are you talking about standard or custom events?

Comment: @misorude i want to get which events are being tracked by a particular pixel like e.g. a pixel `123456` is tracking `content_id` only where can i get this info? appreciate your help...

Comment: Any pixel could be tracking any event, there isn’t a strict 1:1 association between tracked event and pixel id to begin with.

Comment: so we cannot determine how many events (along with event params) a pixel has tracked?

Comment: You see your tracked events in the ads manager or analytics tool, what more do you need?

Comment: i was hoping to get that data via the FB API...